# Is there a way I can run a method many times, incrementing the time before it runs each time?

Tags: c#

I have this code so far:

```
 System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
(p.CommonWord,
 p.JishoJlpt,
 p.JishoWanikani,
 p.JishoExists,
 p.English,
 p.Furigana,
 p.JmdictId,
 p.JmdictHiragana,
 p.Kanji) = GetAll(block, 1);
 if (p.Kanji == "kanj Id not found")
                        {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                            (p.CommonWord,
                             p.JishoJlpt,
                             p.JishoWanikani,
                             p.JishoExists,
                             p.English,
                             p.Furigana,
                             p.JmdictId,
                             p.JmdictHiragana,
                             p.Kanji) = GetAll(block, 2);
                        }
if (p.Kanji == "kanj Id not found")
                        {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
                            (p.CommonWord,
                             p.JishoJlpt,
                             p.JishoWanikani,
                             p.JishoExists,
                             p.English,
                             p.Furigana,
                             p.JmdictId,
                             p.JmdictHiragana,
                             p.Kanji) = GetAll(block, 3);
                        }
if (p.Kanji == "kanj Id not found")
                        {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20000);
                            (p.CommonWord,
                             p.JishoJlpt,
                             p.JishoWanikani,
                             p.JishoExists,
                             p.English,
                             p.Furigana,
                             p.JmdictId,
                             p.JmdictHiragana,
                             p.Kanji) = GetAll(block, 4);
                        }
if (p.Kanji == "kanj Id not found")
                        {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);
                            (p.CommonWord,
                             p.JishoJlpt,
                             p.JishoWanikani,
                             p.JishoExists,
                             p.English,
                             p.Furigana,
                             p.JmdictId,
                             p.JmdictHiragana,
                             p.Kanji) = GetAll(block, 5);
                        }
if (p.Kanji == "kanj Id not found")
                        {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(60000);
                            (p.CommonWord,
                             p.JishoJlpt,
                             p.JishoWanikani,
                             p.JishoExists,
                             p.English,
                             p.Furigana,
                             p.JmdictId,
                             p.JmdictHiragana,
                             p.Kanji) = GetAll(block, 6);
                        }
if (p.Kanji == "kanj Id not found")
                        {
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1200000);
                            (p.CommonWord,
                             p.JishoJlpt,
                             p.JishoWanikani,
                             p.JishoExists,
                             p.English,
                             p.Furigana,
                             p.JmdictId,
                             p.JmdictHiragana,
                             p.Kanji) = GetAll(block, 7);
                        }
```

Can anyone suggest how I can simplify this and still increment the time between each run. What I would like is to start with a 5 second delay and double that each time for 7 iterations before ending even if p.Kanji is "kanj Id not found" after those 7 tries.

Comment: Have you tried a loop? If you made the delay easily calculable, you could just base it off the loop counter.

Comment: and use the loop counter for the GetAll argument

Comment: You can use a timer for that and increase and interval every time

Comment: `how I can simplify this and still increment the time between each run`, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) if it's working. From the looks of it, this doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// start with 5 seconds
int sleepTime = 5000;
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
  // do sleep
  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
  // double sleep time
  sleepTime *= 2;
  // execute
  (p.CommonWord,
   p.JishoJlpt,
   p.JishoWanikani,
   p.JishoExists,
   p.English,
   p.Furigana,
   p.JmdictId,
   p.JmdictHiragana,
   p.Kanji) = GetAll(block, i+1);
  // exit if necessary
  if (p.Kanji != "kanj Id not found")
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make the time to sleep be a variable, perhaps `private int SleepTime = 5000`.
Then change the `if` to a `while`, and after calling your `GetAll` function, set `SleepTime *= 2` or some such, to increase the time it waits on the next loop.

You probably also want to put an exit condition at the bottom of the loop, after increasing `SleepTime` to exit the loop if `SleepTime` exceeds a certain amount (give up)